# Atlassian Confluence, failed to create space

Tags: jira, confluence

I have Atlassian  Jira and Confluence, free pack for 5 members team. The problem is that for a couple of hours I can't create a space into Confluence. When I inspect that dialog I get error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When I press on *Create Space* I get an loading ring and nothing else as related in this pic:
[image]

Comment: If this is a cloud instance, you should contact Atlassian Support. If it's a standalone Confluence server, you should check the atlassian-confluence.log file to get more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: it's a cloud instance, but since it's a free version I can't find Support Entitlement Number (SEN) number to write them for support

Comment: You can check your SEN number in https://my.atlassian.com .

Comment: @SalehParsa thx for help, i'll write them using SEN

Comment: Execuse me, is this resolved?

Comment: @Bugdaily no, it's not. I created new account and I create new space in that acount, then export it, and import in this one. this is the only soulution that I found.